# Acceleration of a falling object as it hits the ground

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, newtonian-gravity, acceleration, free-fall

I am pretty new to physics so forgive me if this seems like a really dumb question.

My Physics I teacher is having us develop a solution to the question:
**You drop your laptop; what is its acceleration as it hits the ground?**

The truth is I have no idea where to start. On top of that, the teacher wants us to include what would happen (conceptually) if the laptop lands on a corner versus one of the sides or what would happen if the laptop was dropped on concrete as opposed to a more forgiving surface.
I was hoping someone could walk me through the process.

Thank to everybody in advance.

Comment: lap tops fall at 9.8 meters per second per second

Comment: Here is how I would think about it: (1) what is it I want to know? [In this case an acceleration] (2) what information do I have? [experience dropping things, the formulas and definition of acceleration, velocity, potential energy and so on] (3) what is the scenario really like, can I see something I can calculate? [what happens when a laptop side or corner moving at some speed encounters a floor of some type?] (4) using this, do I find other things I need to know? [what is the difference between a yielding floor and concrete?]

Answer (score 1):

Assuming no air resistance, the acceleration is constant, that of gravity $9.8 m/sec^2$, until the laptop hits the ground.  Then the acceleration goes to zero over a time determined by the duration of the collision which depends on the rigidity of the laptop and the ground.

As the laptop contacts the ground there are two forces acting on it: the force of gravity down at the center of mass (CM) and the restraining force at the point of contact with the ground.  Assuming the laptop was in vertical free fall (not also moving sideways) the force of restraint is up. Depending on where the point of contact is with respect to the CM, there can be a torque that turns the laptop or not.

In reality contact is an inelastic collision because the laptop does not remain rigid, and if the ground is soft it also does not remain rigid.  For a very soft ground (a pile of feathers) the impact will not destroy the laptop as it is not subject to a very high force of restraint on contact, but instead experiences a gradual force of restraint as it slows down in the soft feathers.  Just like a person jumping off a roof can be saved if the fire department catches the person on a soft net/trampoline.

Answer (score -3):

my theory is that when a ball falls to the ground suppose from 10m you have to multiply it by 9.81m/s(gravitational acceleration) ten you will get the acceleration of the ball when it hits the ground so it is like 9.81 X 10 = 98.1 as like that and at the start of the ball it would be zero this is known as the FREE FALL

Comment: YOU HAVE  TO GIVE ALL THE INFORMATION SINCE IF THERE IS NO HEIGHT YOU CANT HAVE THE ANSWER